# Read Process Memory using Blackbone?

Tags: c++, memory, process

Blackbone is located here:

> https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone

Now what I would like to try to achieve is to read process memory using the aforementioned library.

I have used the pattern scan method to obtain an address in memory which I will later use in the reading process, however I'm getting a bit stuck on whether how I should read the data stored at the Output buffer that the read method is using.

The Read method is structured here:

> https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone/blob/master/src/BlackBone/Process/ProcessMemory.h#L57

And I'm following exactly the same approach taken in the patternscan example provided at:

> https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone/blob/master/src/TestApp/PatternTest.cpp

Just with a little slightly difference:

```
void FindKeys()
{
Process p;
std::vector<DWORD> procs;
std::vector<ptr_t> results;

ptr_t   dwAddress;
size_t  dwSize;
PVOID   pResult;
bool    handleHoles = true;
Process::EnumByName(L"Notepad++.exe", procs);

if (!procs.empty())
{
    p.Attach(procs.front());
    auto pMainMod = p.modules().GetMainModule();

    // Initialize patterns
    PatternSearch ps1{ 0x33, 0xC5, 0x89 };

    // Scan all allocated process memory
    std::wcout << L"[+] Searching for Pattern Scan...\n";
    ps1.SearchRemoteWhole(p, false, 0, results);

    std::wcout << L"[+] Found at Address: [0x";
    std::wcout << std::hex << results[0];
    std::wcout << L"]!\n";

    dwAddress = results[0];
    dwSize = 0x10;

    p.memory().Read(dwAddress, dwSize, pResult, handleHoles);

    results.clear();
}
else
    std::wcout << L"Can't find Notepad++.exe, aborting\n\n";
}
```

My question comes from failing to read pResult, how could I successfully read from it, specifically, I would like to read it as an array of bytes.

Thanks in advance for any further help you guys provide me, it will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Why are you passing `const char*` to `std::wcout` instead of `const wchar_t*` in some places?

Comment: @Brando fixed, because I'm not used to that convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright guys, here is it, fairly simple! and I was over complicating myself.

What I did was to create another variable type `BYTE (unsigned char byte)` named `pResultBytes` and then use `memcpy(&pResultBytes, pResult, dwSize);` where `pResult` is the output buffer from the `Read()` method and `dwSize` is the number of bytes to copy to the new variable.

Next I just started iterating through the `pResultBytes` variable byte by byte and doing the relative conversions to make a hex string and ultimately read it.

Woops almost for got to mention, I also initialized `pResult` to a `new UCHAR[dwSize];` as well, so it eventually has the proper space required for the `memcpy`.

That's it!

Cheers!